# Taking the non-EU terminal by mistake

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-terminals

On August my father and I went to Belgium from Italy and in the airport, however, we mistakenly took the non-domestic gate and we passed our passports through the automated kiosks, then we realised we went on the wrong terminal and we went to the correct one and headed to Brussels

In this case, did the system register our exit from the EU, despite we took no flight in the international terminal, or are entry and exits recorded only when the flight is properly taken?

Comment: Given that you mention using an automated kiosk, do you have a passport from an EU country? If you do, then it doesn’t matter whether your exit or re-entry was recorded, as you’re free to enter and exit as much as you want.

Comment: In most airports you can't get from the international gates to the domestic ones, without going through entry control. What airport did that happen ?

Comment: Bologna. They have just two terminals but I forgot to mention that the departure terminal was split into domestic flights and non-domestic flights, with the police or automated kiosk.

Comment: @Joe It's for residence purposes. I don't want to get my residence revoked, since I'll return to Italy and an exit could result without a re-entry

Comment: I still don't understand the exact circumstances here. Which citizenship do you have and what is your status in Italy or the Schengen area? Since counting the time present in the Schengen area is still based on passport stamps, use of automated gates is essentially limited to persons, for which keeping track of the presence is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm a EU citizen

Comment: I don't want my residence to be revoked for "too much time outside the country", even if I can have it again easily as an Italian citizen

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That's not the case, citizens from many countries can use the automated gates at Schiphol for example (there is an officer standing at a booth after the gates to stamp passports, the screen tells you if you are supposed to walk up to him or her but this is not enforced, nobody stops you if you just walk out).

Comment: @abdul Your residence cannot be “revoked” as an EU citizen. Even for third-country citizens, some sort of process or investigation would be required. In the highly unlikely event that your passport somehow gets flagged, you should have an opportunity to set the record straight.

Comment: How did you switch terminals or go back to the domestic part of the airport? You didn't have to show your passport then?

Comment: @Relaxed The airport had only two terminals, departure and arrivals. I was at the first one and it was divided into two, at the left there were police or kiosks to pass through in order to get to the gates, in the left side there were the gates only.

Comment: @abdul That's more or less what I imagined but once you went through the police check, how do you go back to the other half or the gate for a Schengen flight?

Comment: I simply asked to return back and told them that I went on the wrong gates